# Find the minimum area enclosing polygon of a query point?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, graph-theory

Given a graph where each vertex is a point in the XY-plane and all vertices have degree >= 2 (blue) and 2D query point (x, y) (red)

How can I find the subset of edges of the graph they create the minimum area polygon that encloses (x, y).

For example given:

[image]

The minimum area enclosing polygon is shown in green:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Could you please include an example graph hard-coded in python, so potential answerers can play around with it?

Comment: I guess this question has been closed because it is too difficult for most people.  It is a perfectly good question in computational geometry.

Comment: @ravenspoint So I'm not allow to asked questions that are deemed to difficult. That's odd. So I'll give a simple algorithm but slow which is to consider each edge and then enumerate the non-self intersecting paths between the edges end points which will give a list of polygons and keep the smallest one containing the point. Obviously exponentially slow so I'm hoping there is something better.

Comment: @Stef here https://gist.github.com/nickponline/6eb982671724420623bb221168e673f7

Comment: Theoretically, you are allowed to ask difficult question.  Unfortunately SO has become infested with people who delight in closing questions that they do not understand.

Comment: Is there any additional properties to the graph ? Maybe edges only cross at vertices ?

Comment: @AloisChristen edges can cross edges unfortunately.